# Space between lines in xml

Tags: android, xml

I want this:

[image]

I am getting this instead:

[image]

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="autogenie.plandetail.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Plan:"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Monthly Rental:"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Free Data:"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Overage Charge:"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Network:"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Remarks:"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Features"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
            android:text="@string/features" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#2c75ba"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

My design looks fine:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdLBW.png

I have written entire text in one text view and referring to string resource:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Plandetail</string>
    <string name="features"> &#xA;3GPLUS network &#xA;&#xA;5 WiFi-enabled Devices-Smartphone,Laptop,Tablets
     &#xA; &#xA;Works with Laptop USB,Car Charger and Travel Charger  &#xA;&#xA;Plug and Play &#xA; &#xA;
    EVDO Rev.B 800/1900 MHz-14.7Mbps/5.4Mbps &#xA; &#xA;WiFi  802.11b/g/n &#xA; &#xA;Dual LED indicators for Wi-Fi and Network &#xA; &#xA;Works with Laptop USB,Car Charger and Travel Charger&#xA; &#xA;</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Dear you can define string in String xml and you can put \n in that to make new line so you get break line

Comment: i have posted answer try like that it work well

Comment: and if you want to make with bullets then you have to use TagHandler class it handle html tags

Comment: I have Replace your string and post it check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dear Try like this its work well**

**Make String in string xml like below**

```
    <string name="text">3G Plus network \n\n 5wifi </string>
```

**And use it in your textview text**

**Replace your string With this**

```
 <string name="text">\n3GPLUS network\n\n5 WiFi-enabled Devices-Smartphone,Laptop,Tablets\n\nWorks with Laptop USB,Car Charger and Travel Charger\n\nPlug and Play\n\n
EVDO Rev.B 800/1900 MHz-14.7Mbps/5.4Mbps\n\nWiFi  802.11b/g/n\n\nDual LED indicators for Wi-Fi and Network\n\nWorks with Laptop USB,Car Charger and Travel Charger</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
android:lineSpacingExtra - Extra spacing between lines of text. 
android:lineSpacingMultiplier - Extra spacing between lines of text, as a multiplier.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 0):

please use in textview..

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
```

I hope its solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier in TextViews in your XML file. Let us know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

A big problem i can see in your code is that you need to shrink that button smaller if you keep it smaller youll see the text start to line up better
you can declare the text size of the button  by
 android:textSize="35sp"

android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
and try the second line to help make the button smaller!